# How to timeout a large SQL query in R

Tags: sql, r

I have a SQL query I'm running in RODBC. Some of the parameters are user defined and there is a risk of running a huge SQL query.

I'd like to detect and stop any SQL queries that run over a certain amount of time.

I've looked at R.utils but it doesn't seem to time out:

```
R.utils::withTimeout({sqlQuery(ch, sql)}, timeout = 1.08)
```